# How to pass a String with the character "@" as part of the string?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, char, parameter-passing, procedure

this is my simple Stored Procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertar_Empleado]
@nombre varchar(40),
@apellido varchar (40),
@dni varchar(7),
@direccion int,
@usuario varchar (50),
@contraseña varchar(20),
@mail varchar(50),
@tel varchar(20),
@tipo int

as

insert into Empleados(nombre, apellido, dni, id_direccion ,id_tipoEmpleado, mail,
telefono, usuario, pass)
values(@nombre, @apellido, @dni, @direccion,  @tipo, @mail, @tel, @usuario, 
@contraseña)
```

The problem is that the parameter @usuario will always contain a string like "@Peter" or "@George", so when I insert some rows the field "usuario" has a value like "Peter" or "George" ignoring the @ character. I need this cause it's a way to identify that this user is a special type of user. Any idea?

**RS:

This is the first part:**

```
 public void InsertarCliente(Cliente nCliente, SqlConnection conec, SqlTransaction transac)
    {
        Datos objDatos = new Datos();
        SqlParameter[] objParametros = new SqlParameter[9];

        objParametros[0] = new SqlParameter("@nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
        objParametros[0].Value = nCliente.Nombre;

        objParametros[1] = new SqlParameter("@apellido", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
        objParametros[1].Value = nCliente.Apellido;

        objParametros[2] = new SqlParameter("@dni", SqlDbType.VarChar, 9);
        objParametros[2].Value = nCliente.Dni;

        objParametros[3] = new SqlParameter("@direccion", SqlDbType.Int, 6);
        objParametros[3].Value = nCliente.Direccion;

        objParametros[4] = new SqlParameter("@tipo", SqlDbType.Int, 3);
        objParametros[4].Value = null;

        objParametros[5] = new SqlParameter("@mail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        objParametros[5].Value = nCliente.Mail;

        objParametros[6] = new SqlParameter("@tel", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
        objParametros[6].Value = nCliente.Telefono;

        objParametros[7] = new SqlParameter("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        objParametros[7].Value = nCliente.Nombre;

        objParametros[8] = new SqlParameter("@contraseña", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
        objParametros[8].Value = nCliente.Nombre;


        try
        {

            if (nCliente.Usuario.StartsWith("@"))
            {
                objParametros[4].Value = 1;
                objDatos.ExecuteNonQuery("insertar_Empleado", ref objParametros, ref conec, ref transac);
            }

            else
            {
                objParametros[4].Value = 3;
                objDatos.ExecuteNonQuery("insertar_Cliente", ref objParametros, ref conec, ref transac);
            }

            

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error al insertar el Cliente", ex);
        }
    
    }
```

**The second part is a generic way to use stored stored procedures that I use:**

```
public void ExecuteNonQuery(string nombreSP , ref SqlParameter[] param, ref SqlConnection objConn, ref SqlTransaction objTran)
    {
        //Hago que el try encierre todo el bloque del procedimiento, sino me puede quedar la transacción colgada 

        try 
        {    
   
                SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand();
                objCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                objCommand.CommandText = nombreSP;
                //La conexión que pasé como parámetro
                objCommand.Connection = objConn;
                //la transacción que pasé como parámetro
                objCommand.Transaction = objTran;

                foreach (SqlParameter parametro in param)
                {
                    objCommand.Parameters.Add(parametro);
     
                }
                

                objCommand.Connection = objConn;

                objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
    
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you passing values to the stored procedure? Can you post that part of your code.

Comment: As mentioned I suspect you are adding your parameters incorrectly. [This simplified example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b9c9/1) works fine.

Comment: OMG this stupid errors again... jajja.. I'll correct this and I'll try to insert again! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason you are not seeing the `@` for any value in the `usario` field is that you are adding the Name to this parameter here:

```
objParametros[7] = new SqlParameter("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
objParametros[7].Value = nCliente.Nombre;
```

I think it should be

```
objParametros[7] = new SqlParameter("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
objParametros[7].Value = nCliente.Usuario;
```

As a non related point, this line is redundant:

```
objParametros[4].Value = null;
```

The value will be `null` by default, and this is not the equivalent of `NULL` in the database. The equivalent is `DbNull.Value`.

Comment: Yeap, this was the dumb error... this happened cause I copied the code many times in different proyects and in some cases i didnt correct i properly. Thanks... and about de Null value I didn't realize about the null by default... i'm finishing this for an University Exam and it's a long time since i programmed the first part of this code!